# Django user.set_password(password) is not hashing the password

Tags: django, django-models, django-login, django-custom-user, django-mssql

I have wrote Custom user Model in Django everything is working fine except password is not being hashed when but when I had created the superuser password was hashed here are my models for custom user and custom user manager
model.py()

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"]
    object=CustomUserManager()


class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The given email must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)  
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


    def create_user(self,username ,email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        return self._create_user( username,email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self,username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")

        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

admin.site.register(get_user_model())

should i use this
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
and how to use this

Comment: How do you use this? Do you have a form, or something that uses that user model?

Comment: this cant work as you have there `object=CustomUserManager()` instead of `objects = CustomUserManager()` (singular `object` vs plural `objects`)

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike No i use admin interface to make a user as my project is just started

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko i had done objects but still no change buddy

Comment: @AbdullahMoudood: can you share the admin you defined for the user model?

Comment: @AbdullahMoudood this is definitely a fix you should apply. If this doesnt work yet, that means there is yet another problem. Anyway - does it work as expected via `manage.py createsuperuser` or is the behaviour the same as when you create it in admin? This should help you further identify where the issue could be... buddy.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko no admin is registered perfectly no issue in that everything is working fine except that password is not being hashed for only regular user i have registered another user as admin using same interface password is being hashed

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike no i have done nothing in admin.py except for regular practices which is admin.site.register(model)

Comment: @AbdullahMoudood: and that means Django will not use the `.create_user` method, but just use `.create(..)` and treat it as a *regular* model...

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike guide me what should i do so that this issue will be solved please

Comment: @AbdullahMoudood: can you please edit the question with the current admin?

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike check

Comment: Thank you both finally done with this problem

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `UserAdmin` (or class inherited from it), as changing the password is done via special password form instead of default text field

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

admin.site.register(get_user_model(), UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Yess I have also done the same thing instead I had use custom admin class and defined field set tuple